# Dynamic Column Name with current date

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to rename some column headers to be the current and following months. (August,September,November,etc) I have tried a couple options from creating a new table to editing the M code, is this possible in Power BI?

New Table =
SELECTCOLUMNS(
Sheet1,
Month(Today()), Sheet1[Month 1])

Comment: I would recommend using a calendar table to drive something like this. You can then don't have to set the columns names, it will be dynamic